# What does ため do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> ダンジョンへもぐる時点でサポーターも**等しく危険に晒されているため**、一概にはそう言えない筈なのだが、リリは訂正することなく持論を続ける。

I'm not sure how to interpret ため in that part of the sentence. Does it still mean for the sake of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ため has both "aim" and "cause" readings, so used as a postposition, it stands for either "for the sake of" or "due to", pretty much like English "on account of" does.

In this case, it's the latter.

> ***Since** supporters are equally exposing themselves to danger once they go down into the dungeon...*

Comment: According to http://tangorin.com/general/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81, ため means `consequence;  result;  effect`. An example sentence for that specific meaning is `霧のため全列車は運転休止となった。(Railroad service was suspended because of the fog.)`

Comment: @crocket I don't think it's the commonest interpretation. ため etymologically means "benefit", and then "aim", then "reason".

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why `consequence; result; effect` is tied to that example sentence that treats ため as `cause`. Can you explain? On jisho, `consequence; result; effect` is tied to `それは、おまえの声をよく聞くためだよ (It is in order to hear your voice well.)`. Here, ため is treated as `aim`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it means the English word "because" in this case.