# What is the meaning of 「ため」 in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

I understand that ため means "in order to" or "goal".

I don't understand how it works in this sentence though. Could someone please explain.

> バスの事故が続いている**ため**出発前に警察などが調べ

This is how I interpret it:

> The bus accident | in order to continue being | before the departure | Police etc investigate

Comment: Duplicate? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29917/7810

Answer (score 3):

「ため」 has ***many*** meanings.  In this context, it means "because (of)", "owing to", etc.

> "Because bus accidents continue to take place, the police and ~~~~ before departures."

***Because*** you cut off the sentence in the middle, I could not translate it fully.

「文が途中で切れている**ため**、完全には訳せません。」