# Use of ため in the next sentence

Tags: grammar

I have my cellphone in japanese to immerse myself as much as I can in the language, and when my facebook failed, this message popped up:
「問題が発出した**ため**Facebookを終了しました。」
By context I can understand that "A problem happened with Facebook so it needs to be terminated" but can't understand the 発出したため part. 
I learned the ため as "for the sake of", but I don't think its trying to say "for the sake of the issue", right?

Thank you before hand.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30671/i-keep-seeing-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81

Comment: "'Tame' implies that there is a cause-and-effect relationship between what precedes it and what follows it. " I think that sums it up pretty good, even though we usually think tame as "in order to", if we follow this definition, it makes a lot of sense IMO. Source: https://www.japanesepod101.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=653

Comment: `発出` -- 「発生」ですよね？「出」→「生」

Comment: ため can be translated as "because", "due to", "as a result of"
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/為/#je-46719

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was a bit busy this days, the translation as "as a result of" helped a lot, thanks!