# What meaning does ため have in this particular sentence?

Tags: meaning, nouns

On http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010492331000/k10010492331000.html,
you can find

> 大きな揺れだけではなくて、地面が動いたため、建物が倒れたり、山が崩れたりして大きな被害が出たと思います。

I don't understand what `ため` means in this sentence.
What does it mean?

Comment: as a consequence\due to?

Comment: duplicate? -> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29917 , http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30671

Comment: @chocolate I think it could be duplicate of one of those, but I'd like an answer that refers to an authoritative external reference.

Comment: @crocket What references are you using? Doesn't it have an entry for ため?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I used jisho, but it doesn't contain an example sentence that shows how ため is used as `because of` and `owing to`.

Comment: The linked question lacked an authoritative external reference, so I added one myself.

Comment: この辞書も参考になるかも？[プログレッシブ和英](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/46719/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81/)：2 〔理由，原因〕because 「昨日風邪のため学校を休んだ」「彼が軽率だったために大変迷惑をこうむった」、または[マギー先生 理由](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/08/14/%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1riyuuhow-to-make-excuses-explain-reasons-in-japanese-request-lesson/)：「まだ給料が出ていない[為]{ため}、返せません」「男性が亡くなっていた場所の近くにはスズメバチの巣があったため、警察は蜂に刺されて亡くなったと考えています。」

Comment: @chocolate That's good to know.